# Conver Json Column Object Array to pandas DataFrame ( python )

Tags: python, pandas

I need a little help to convert the column (options) json array to a pandas dataframe.
Output example of my already converted json, but I have a single column options where I need to convert this Array.
I need to separate all fields correctly from options column.

Json File for this question : https://pastebin.com/qnMrB0Y8

```
json_entrada = 'deal_fields.json'
excel_saida = 'deal_fields.xlsx'
planilha = 'Sheet1'

with open(json_entrada, 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
start_time = time.time()
df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=['data'])
grava_excel = df.to_excel(excel_saida)
```

The output of the file is like this
[image: Output]

Comment: What is the dictionary in your post? Is that your `data` variable?

Comment: Yes , you are correct

Comment: What are the columns you want in your dataframe? Can you add a snapshot of what the final dataframe should look like?

Comment: I need all columns , but the Options columnbut the options column i didn't get due to it being an  json array, follow the json file that i am using : https://pastebin.com/qnMrB0Y8

Comment: Your "mandatory_flag" and "bulk_edit_allowed_conditions" columns also contain jsons. Include your expected output in your OP.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create two dataframes:

   - one with all data except "options",
   - one with just the "options" data
2. `join` them

You'll need to rename the "id" key within options as you also have another "id" key.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data).drop("options", axis=1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data["options"]).rename(columns={"id":"option_id"})
output = df1.join(df2)

>>> output
      id     key    name  ...  mandatory_flag option_id      label
0  12457  status  Status  ...            True      open  Em aberto
1  12457  status  Status  ...            True      lost    Perdido
2  12457  status  Status  ...            True       won      Ganho
3  12457  status  Status  ...            True   deleted  ExcluÃ­do

[4 rows x 22 columns]
```

Or in a single line:

```
output = pd.DataFrame(data).drop("options", axis=1).join(pd.DataFrame(data["options"]).rename(columns={"id":"option_id"}))
```

Comment: Sorry but i couldn't do it :   raise KeyError(f"{list(labels[mask])} not found in axis")
KeyError: "['options'] not found in axis" . Follow the Json file that  i'm using : https://pastebin.com/qnMrB0Y8